# Edgy Corners / Pixelated circular icon when decoding from Bitmap factory | Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am drawing the same **circular icon** with two different approaches and getting different results. One is **perfect round shape** and another one is **Edgy**.

When I try to show image in ImageView gives me this result

[image]

When I tried to show by using bitmap decoding

[image]

```
Bitmap icon = getBitmap(getActivity(),R.drawable.ic_access_time_white_48dp);
RectF iconDest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - width - 2 * (iconSize ), (float) itemView.getTop() + iconSize, (float) itemView.getRight() - width, (float) itemView.getBottom() - iconSize);
c.drawBitmap(icon, null, iconDest, p);
```

Get bitmap function

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

private static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
    }
}
```

so how to get rounded circular image like in first option using second method.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: @CzarMatt How to show perfect circle in the second case.